# How well does MS Word 2007 and MS Power Point 2007 work in Wine?

Tags: wine, microsoft-office

I would like to use install Ubuntu for a brother, but he needs MS Word and MS Power Point for work.

Open alternatives apart, how well does MS Word 2007 and MS Power Point 2007 work in Wine?

Comment: you should try libreoffice it has very good compatibilty with both doc,ppt and docx,pptx. also softmaker office (40$) is linux native and has full compatibility with msoffice.

Comment: I've been using Word 2007 on my linux computer for about a year now with just Wine, and it works pretty good - mostly usable for work. I do find some oddities here and there, usually just need to close the document and re-open when that happens.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## [playonlinux](http://packages.ubuntu.com/playonlinux) [image: Install playonlinux]

is a piece of software which allows you to easily install and use numerous games and softwares designed to run with Microsoft®'s Windows®.

For Ubuntu, PlayOnLinux is available in the universe repository. If you have this repository enables, you can install it by typing the command:

```
sudo apt-get install playonlinux
```

After playonlinux is installed, do the following

1. Open Playonlinux

   Go to your menu and open **Application-->Games-->PlayOnlinux**

[image]

2. Click **Next**
3. Select from where you will install Microsoft office 2007
4. enter you Microsoft Office 2007 KEY
5. Accept the term and conditions then click continue
6. Click **install now** to start the installation of Microsoft Office 2007
7. Create Menu and Desktop shortcuts

Answer (score 2):

You can find out how well programs run in wine using the [AppDB](http://appdb.winehq.org/index.php):

- [Word 2007](http://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=version&iId=12811&iTestingId=42359&bShowAll=true&sAllBugs) - **Bronze**
- [Power Point 2007](http://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=version&iId=12813) - **Bronze**

On AppDB, software is given one of the following ratings:

- **Platinum** (Software will install and run without requiring any extra steps, tricks or workarounds)
- **Gold** (Working in all aspects)
- **Silver** (Working well)
- **Bronze** (Mostly Usable)
- **Garbage** (It don't fly too well)

So, they are mostly usable but you may have a few issues.

[See this wiki page for detailed information about AppDB.](http://wiki.jswindle.com/index.php/Wine_Application_Database)

Answer (score 0):

I have installed Office via playonlinux. Functionally it's ok, but I find it irritating because plain Arial font looks like its bold. Also handling graphics in Office is less than perfect.