# Where did PlayOnLinux install Microsoft Office 2007?

Tags: microsoft-office, playonlinux

After I installed playonlinux, I immediately installed the Microsoft office 2007. I pasted an .iso image on my desktop and extracted it on a folder, and after that I installed it using the playonlinux.

After several loadings the playonlinux prompted installing Internet Explorer 6 and after that, it said that office 2007 was successfully installed, and I can't find where is office 2007 installed. Can you help me?

Comment: related question -> http://askubuntu.com/questions/24964/how-well-does-ms-word-2007-and-ms-power-point-2007-work-in-wine/24970#24970

Comment: I strongly recommend this approach: http://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=version&iId=4992 - also as answer here http://askubuntu.com/a/258347/47206

Answer (score 4):

Maybe in `~/.playonlinux/wineprefix/Microsoft\ Office\ 2007/dosdevices/c:/Program\ Files/Microsoft\ Office\ 2007` ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

- open the software manager, install wine
- check to see if both wine and playonlinux are up to date from the Q
- when the window saying that office was installed, don't click the finish or close button on the office window, wait until playonlinux has finished installing

  playonlinux will prompt you with "do you want to add on your desktop or in your menu".
- If success you will see an icon in the play on linux window and from the menu in other and in wine

Answer (score 0):

It must have promoted you for a menu item if it was created you can acces it from Applications -> PlayOnLinux -> ms office .

Answer (score 0):

With PlayOnLinux, you have to make the shortcuts manually when you set up the wine prefix and install the programs. You do this when you install it. After you run the installation program you are asked if you want to make a shortcut. Answer in the affirmative and you will have to choose which ".exe" file the shortcut will refer to, and the shortcuts name. Then the process will loop, in case you want to add extra shortcuts. Once done, the shortcuts will appear in the menus (if you specified it) and the PlayOnLinux list with a googly eyes icon (dont ask why)