# Can Wine support Office 2007?

Tags: wine

I tried installing Office 2007 in Ubuntu with Wine but it was throwing an error after installing and also when I tried to open a PowerPoint document and save it. Has anybody gotten Office 2007 installed without any issues? Please help me.

Comment: I'd suggest just using LibreOffice, which should have come free with your Ubuntu out of the box. I haven't found anything I could do in Office that I couldn't do in LibreOffice just as easily.

Comment: But is not as good as office 2007...everyone will accept it

Comment: In what way is it not as good as Office 2007? And I'm not sure what you mean by 'everyone will accept it'.

Comment: "but it was throwing an error" --> Yup, very useful information here...

Comment: @Don this question is not about *LibreOffice*, but about M$ office.

Comment: please consider protecting this question

Comment: @user49848 You can install _MS Office 2007_, through _playonlinux_. Open a Terminal with **Ctrl+Alt+T** and type ` sudo apt-get install playonlinux`. For detailed instructions follow this [link](http://www.unixmen.com/install-ms-office2007-on-ubuntu-using-playonlinux/).

Comment: @efthialex: this asks for a full answer, especially considering that playonlinux might provide other interesting options, like using different wine versions for different applications at the same time (http://ubuntu.igameilive.com/2010/02/how-to-use-multiple-versions-of-wine-in.html), given that regressions are a big issue considering wine. i myself haven't tried this, and have not tried office2007 in playonlinux so i cannot post an answer, but could you?

Answer (score 24):

You can install MS Office 2007, with the help of **PlayOnLinux**. PlayOnLinux is a graphical front-end for the Wine software compatibility layer which aims to simplify the installation of Windows-based applications.

### 1. Installation of PlayOnLinux

You can install **PlayOnLinux** from Ubuntu Software Center

[image: Download]

**or** open a **Terminal** with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd> and type:

`sudo apt-get install playonlinux` and fill in your password.

[image]

Then type `Y` or `yes` and hit <kbd>Enter ↵</kbd> to install the package.

[image]

After a while you will need to accept the EULA of `mscorefonts`. To select the *OK* option, hit  <kbd>⇆ TAB</kbd>  and then <kbd>Enter ↵</kbd>.

[image]

[image]

When the installation process is finished open **PlayOnLinux** from dash

[image]

The first time you open it, click *Next* to set up the **PlayOnLinux** environment.

[image]

[image]

After that everything is set up.

### 2. Mount *.iso or CD-ROM

At this momment, you need to mount the `.iso` or place in the CD that contains the MS Office 2007.

If you have a `.iso` file open a **Terminal** and type

`sudo mkdir /media/office07` With this command you'll create a folder with the name office07 in /media.

Next type

`sudo mount -o loop ~/filename.iso /media/office07` to mount the image into our new directory.

### 3. Install MS Office 2007

Now switch on PlayonLinux window and click on the button *Install* to install a new software.

[image]

Next, go on the category *Office*, choose *Microsoft Office 2007* and click in the button *Install*.

[image]

Hit *Next*

[image]

After some time you will be asked to install **Gecko Installer**. Hit the *Install* button.

[image]

When the installation of Gecko Installer is finished you will have to choose where is your CD/.iso is mounted and click *Next*.

[image]

At last continue as usually

[image]

When you finish with installation you will have three new shortcuts in your desktop (Word, Excel, Powerpoint)

[image]

Comment: great, i feel i'll be needing that soon. in case you come about testing that feature with multiple wine versions that i mentioned in the other comment, please update your answer in the future. i'll do the same in case i am in the position to talk about that. i'm very happy msoffice in linux becomes so easy and a last reason to mess with the other OS is gone

Comment: what version of wine have you tested? what do you think about the regressions reported here? (http://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=version&iId=4992). have you met this kind of problem?

Comment: @cipricus PlayOnLinux automatically installs Office 2007 under wine 1.2.3. I didn't face any issues the last 6 months.

Comment: Can you move the shortcuts to the Unity Launcher?

Comment: @com.BOY

Yes you can. Take a look at this post :

http://askubuntu.com/questions/159103/how-can-i-add-playonlinux-programs-in-the-unity-dash

Answer (score 9):

Definitely yes, in Wine 1.5.

Details on the WineHQ site: [***here***](http://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=version&iId=4992).

That is my source, I'll add instructions from there.

(**Pay attention to what they say there**, like: "There are many howtos for installing Office 2007 floating about the internet. These howtos are rarely maintained by their authors, and because of **the rapid rate of Wine development**, even ones that were accurate at the time they were posted **quickly become outdated**.

In the case of Office 2007, **many of these outside howtos call for installing a long list of winetricks that are unnecessary to install in current Wine. Some of these tweaks can, in fact, prevent Office apps from working properly**.

The only howto for installing Office 2007 that is supported here is the one on this page."

"­No overrides are nee­ded to install Microsoft Office 2007. However to get Microsoft Office 2007 to run correctly once it has been installed some overrides may be necessary. See below for instructions."

"**Do not install riched20 with winetricks. Office 2007 installs its own version of riched20.**")

Because myself had already installed those long lists of winetricks mentioned above, I had to **uninstall and reinstall Wine completely before proceeding** as stated below.

The problems appear with certain versions of Wine.

The solution is to keep oneself updated to the WineHQ instructions.

Latest versions of Wine are best. Also, latest versions of Office (2007 and 2010) are easier to install than the older ones.

The safest would be to install Office 2007 after a fresh installation of Wine 1.5 (present latest: I will update in time).

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-wine/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install wine1.5
```

Go to Menu, 'Configure Wine' and make sure your version of wine is set to **Windows XP**.

[image]

Install Office 2007.
(Open the disk and right click on setup.exe and select "Open with wine windows program loader.")
The progress bar in the installer window may stop when it reaches about 2/3 of the way. The installation is continuing, even though the progress bar is not moving. Wait for it to finish.

After installation:

In 'Configure Wine', under the Libraries tab in the area labeled "New override for library" type in `riched20.dll` and click on **Add**.
You will see it appear in the list below. Now select the `riched20` in the list that we just added and click on the **Edit** button.
Set it to **Native (Windows)** and click **OK**.

[image]

This will allow Powerpoint and the other applications to run correctly.

---

What comes bellow I did it beyond what what the above site says, so it might involve certain risks. It seems that it is very important not to use winetricks and so on before installing as stated here and at [the WineHQ address](http://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=version&iId=4992).

---

Optionally, what I did was to install all fonts and improve appearance like [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/219795/47206).

Also, I like to have the classic menus (XP/2003) at hand, added in  a tab beside the new ones: there are different addons for that but the one I use in Windows7 doesn't seem to work in Wine so I have installed [this](http://www.ubit.ch/software/ubitmenu-languages/), which is add-supported. (Please give me a comment with a link to one that is cleaner and works as expected if you find one.)

---

The [SaveAsPDFandXPS](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=7) add-in appears to be working as expected.

Answer (score 3):

You could give [playonlinux](http://www.playonlinux.com/en/) a try. It has fairly decent office 2007 tools. Just start playonlinux and install office 2007 using either cd or an .exe file. Under 12.10 it works relatively fine, but it does not support typing Hebrew, Arabic and so (unless you configure them). Also installing add-ons (bibliography managers and the like) is all but obvious.

Comment: considering the possibility of regressions in wine, using different wine versions at the same time would be great: and playonlinux might be able to provide this (have not tried it myself but this feature surely deserves to be tested): http://ubuntu.igameilive.com/2010/02/how-to-use-multiple-versions-of-wine-in.html

Comment: also: http://askubuntu.com/q/245900/47206

Answer (score 2):

Yes, `wine` supports installing Office 2007. I recently installed it on my laptop and as you said, it didn't give any errors **while** installing but when you try to save and close the document, it pops up 2-3 error messages, which if you read carefully, can be safely ignored. However, as you said, PowerPoint does not seem to start easily from the `dash`. To open PowerPoint, open a Terminal and go the path where you have installed `Office` and type

`wine PPTVIEW.EXE`

To locate where you have installed Office, type

`locate PPTVIEW.EXE`

on the terminal, which will indirectly give you the path where Office is installed.

If you are not able to open a document, then please post the output of

```
wine /home/$USER/.wine/drive_c/Program\ Files\ \(x86\)/Microsoft\ Office/Office12/PPTVIEW.EXE
```

of whatever path Office is installed on as a comment to this answer.

Comment: I have no error on saving as far as I can tell. See my answer with that WineHQ link - there seem to be a lot of errors possible outside the framework  that is clearly stated there: no winetricks in order to install, and so on. fresh wine install is what i've used

Comment: Are you talking about the messages that you get on terminal when you install/open one of these applications like Word or Excel or PowerPoint? If yes, you can safely ignore them, as they are not *error* messages, they are either warnings or simple execution time messages.

Comment: I have no errors or message errors whatsoever: I was referring to **possible** errors like the ones you report, which might be related to not following strictly these instructions (http://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=version&iId=4992)

Comment: Yes, I was addressing you @cipricus. Sorry not to have mentioned you. Then that's great, great going!

Answer (score 0):

As of Wine 1.6.2 through Wine devel 1.9.16, Excel 2007 runs without any Play on Linux. Macros work, but there are few weird oddities:

1. The file open/save dialogs lack any attributes - only the filenames are displayed. This is a [know issue](https://bugs.winehq.org/show_bug.cgi?id=32935) dating since 2013.

   [image: File attributes are missing]
2. The exact same .xlsx file that opens perfectly fine in the exact same copy of MS Office 2007 installed in an XP SP3 VM, fails to open in Excel on Wine, with the message that it found ["unreadable content"](https://bugs.winehq.org/show_bug.cgi?id=41155) (trying to recover fails with `The workbook cannot be opened or repaired by Microsoft Except because it is corrupt.`):

   [image: Excel found unreadable content in ... Do you want to recover the contents of this workbook? If you trust the source of this workbook, click Yes.]