# How can I add PlayOnLinux programs in the Unity dash?

Tags: unity, launcher, playonlinux

I wonder if there is any way to add the programs installed in PlayOnLinux to the Unity dash.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you install applications with PlayOnLinux, there is an option to add the a launcher (Desktop file) to the menu. This will create application launcher in `~/.local/share/applications`, which means that the launcher will show up in the Unity Dash.

If this does not work, you can choose the option to place a launcher on the Desktop, and then manually move it to this folder.

Now, keep in mind that Unity does not always pick up when a launcher is added to this folder, so in order for the launcher to show up, you must either log out and log back in, or restart Unity.

To restart Unity, run `unity` in the run dialogue (press <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>f2</kbd> to get the run dialogue).

Comment: I'm sorry, I think I mixed up launcher and dash. I thought the thing that opens if I press meta was the launcher. I will correct my question.

Comment: By dash, you mean the thing that exists at the left and swooshes out containing program buttons?  If so, the Dash contains launcher files