# How can I properly add PlayOnLinux programs to the Unity Launcher?

Tags: unity, launcher, wine, playonlinux, evernote

I have a PlayOnLinux app (Evernote) that runs great, but I would like to pin it to the Unity launcher.    I already have a shortcut in the Dash and I can pin that to the Launcher, but then running it results in the app showing a wine icon in the launcher and not the icon that the shortcut had.  The shortcut I have is a PlayOnLinux created shortcut and the command is:

`/usr/share/playonlinux/playonlinux --run "Evernote"`

I read elsewhere that in order to properly pin a wine app to the Unity Launcher the command has to look like this:

`env WINEPREFIX="/home/myname/.PlayOnLinux/wineprefix/wine1.4_en4.5" wine 'C:\\Program Files\\Evernote\\Evernote\\Evernote.exe'`

This works great in terms of launching and having Unity use the right icon on the Launcher, but this fails because the "wine" I am running is not the POL 1.4, but rather the system installed version.  Playing around with the WINELOADER environment variable did not help.

---

NOTE: This question is not a duplicate of [How can I add PlayOnLinux programs in the Unity dash?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/159103/how-can-i-add-playonlinux-programs-in-the-unity-dash) as I already have the launcher shortcut in the Dash.

Comment: Have you tried making a separate .desktop file in /usr/share/applications ? .desktop files examples http://askubuntu.com/questions/35488/what-custom-launchers-and-unity-quicklists-are-available or .desktop  http://standards.freedesktop.org/desktop-entry-spec/latest/ar01s05.html

Comment: Yes - the desktop file that launches Evernote via PlayOnLinux gives me the screwed up icons on the launcher, and the one that launches Evernote via wine uses the wrong version of Wine.  Each one fails for different reasons.

Comment: I have the same problem and would love for it to be fixed. I have no idea if this would be helpful information, but I have noticed that _sometimes_ the program (I personally am having this problem with Microsoft Office 2010) opens on the icon that I have pinned to the launcher.

Comment: Have you look at [Everpad](http://discussion.evernote.com/topic/31947-everpad-evernote-for-linux/)?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As of in Ubuntu 13.04 with the latest PlayOnLinux running Evernote and/or join.me in a  Wine 1.5.28 bottle...this problem has just disappeared on its own.

I just have PlayOnLinux create the shortcuts on my desktop and then I copy them to `~/.local/share/applications` log out and log back in.  Then I take these Dash shortcuts and drag them to the launcher.

Comment: confirming this works flawlessly on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Comment: An alternative to logging out is to run the command `sudo update-desktop-database`. Anyways thanks for this info