# Cannot run Word2007 on Wine 1.4 / Ubuntu 12.10

Tags: 12.10, wine, microsoft-office

After a fresh install of Ubuntu 12.10 and Wine 1.4 (all from Ubuntu repositories) and after installing MS-Office 2007, when starting Word, beside the Word itself, another window running Office Setup comes up saying that something else needs to be configured. Has anyone seen such a thing?

Comment: Why not you use an alternative that was designed to run in Ubuntu, such as LibreOffice?

Comment: possible duplicate: http://askubuntu.com/q/155809/47206. see answer there

Answer (score 0):

Wine is not very good.  There is probably some kind of DLL missing, and Office tries to fix it with the installer.  Have you tried [link](http://www.libreoffice.org/)?

Comment: I use LibreOffice, but for some files it doesn't open them correctly. As of now I am running Windows+Office on VBOX.

Comment: I was going to suggest a VM instead of Wine.

Answer (score 0):

I'm trying to do the same, but when I insert Office 2007 disk, I don't see any files at all.  How can I view files on an Office 2007 disk in Ubuntu 12.10.  I too have freshly installed Wine (1.4.1) and Playonlinux (4.1.1).

Answer (score 0):

Just now I upgraded ubuntu 12.10 from 12.04. I can able to run word2007 doc/docx files. I have wine-1.5.16 and playOnLinux 4.1.8. May be upgrade of wine will fix your problem.