# UBUNTU plus windows office

Tags: installation, windows-7, compatibility, antivirus, viruses

Can I install only UBUNTU as an operating system and use Windows Office and the work program? Would this minimize or eliminate the virus problem we have with windows?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [this blog post](http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/easily-install-microsoft-office-2007-linux/) for info on installing Microsoft Office in Linux. But you should ask yourself if you *really* need to. If you're just going to be word processing and making spreadsheets etc then there are plenty of **free** Linux based options that will be more or less compatible with MS Office. On the other hand if you need total compatibility with Microsoft Office (for other users who may use your files on Windows, for example), then you may want to look at installing MS Office under Linux.

As far as viruses go, Linux is far more secure than Windows, but not entirely secure. I doubt installing Windows software in Linux would make it less secure. Take a look at [this article](https://www.linux.com/learn/tutorials/284124-myth-busting-is-linux-immune-to-viruses) on Linux viruses. Generally Windows PC's get viruses because the user does something *not so clever*. Like opening dodgy looking email attachments, or visiting dodgy websites and downloading dodgy files. This human part won't change just because the user is using a Linux machine. They'll still do silly things, it's just that most of the viruses target Windows security flaws, as it's the most commonly used platform. If someone was to write a virus targeting Linux then the Linux machine could just as easily get infected.

Answer (score 0):

Yes definitely it will work in Ubuntu. Microsoft Office has some great advantages over other Office Suite, thus people prefer it over others. There are many ways you can use **MS Office**. For example, install MS Office using **Wine**, **PlayOnLinux** and **Cross Over**. The easy way to install is use latest **Wine1.6**.

Follow some easy steps and you will get **MS Office** working for you. Open terminal(<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>) and execute following commands:

- Adding repository for latest Wine1.6.

  ```
  $ sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-wine/ppa
  ```
- Updating repository:

  ```
  $ sudo apt-get update
  ```
- Installing wine:

  ```
  $ sudo apt-get install wine.
  ```

  now you can also install latest wine using synaptic package manager. Search for wine1.6.

When finished, install MS Office by executing setup.exe through Wine. Hope it works for you without any problem.

**Get more help**

- [Installing MS Office in Wine](http://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=version&iId=4992)
- [Installing in PlayOnLinux](https://askubuntu.com/questions/155809/can-wine-support-office-2007)
- [Installing in CrossOver](http://www.codeweavers.com/compatibility/browse/name?app_id=10518)