# Is it possible to install Microsoft Office without a CD?

Tags: software-installation, playonlinux, microsoft-office

I have been a Windows user since... well... always. Now I decided to try Linux Ubuntu, and found out it looks way much better.

The problem is, I am a student and constantly need Microsoft Word/Excel/Powerpoint, and LibreOffice just isn't the same thing. When I have to update something on Excel, when I open the same archive on Windows some formatation of it is changed. That's why I would like to install Microsoft Windows.

I do not have the installation CD. However, I already have the Microsoft Office installed on Windows. I have tried the convenient methods to install it through PlayOnLinux, but I keep stuck on this part

https://i.stack.imgur.com/2GPmT.png

From:[Can Wine support Office 2007?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/155809/can-wine-support-office-2007/258717#258717)

My question is: Can I install it through the archives it created on Windows when it was there installed or would I really need the CD for that and, therefore, not being able to install? Would I be able to borrow a CD from someone?

Thank you.

Comment: If you still have your product key (or can [recover it](http://superuser.com/q/176306/51778)), you may be able to [download the CD from Microsoft](https://www.microsoft.com/office/downloads/).

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu has extensive documentation on installing and using Microsoft Office in Ubuntu.

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Microsoft_Office

Also, have you seen the latest version of Libreoffice? It is very different from previous versions and much improved. You might want to visit their site and read up on it.