# Privileges Denied : Trying to Change setting of an application

Tags: permissions, wine

I am a newbee, i've installed wine-1.6.1 (following , [Can Wine support Office 2007?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/155809/can-wine-support-office-2007)). Later i did install IDM successfully, right clicking the .exe file and choosing "open with wine windows program loader".

While i was trying to change options of IDM, it prompts

1. You do not have administrative privileges or you did not allow IDM helper program to execute as Administrator (is it because, i did not you sudo to install this application)
2. You pressed Cancel button during IDM network driver installation (which i recall not doing it any way along the installation procedure)
3. You blocked IDM network driver startup or installation by means of the thrid-party security software or antivirus

so how do i get the administrative rights over this application without having to remove and reinstall using sudo.

I have tried to find solution over the internet but in vain. ALl i could find is information on usage of sudo and root. I have also tried using chmod to change the wrx rights.

I'm using Ubuntu 12.04 LTS and wine-1.6.1