# cannot install MS office 2007 on ubuntu 18.04.01 via Playonlinux

Tags: wine, playonlinux

My question is not a duplicate because

- I don't use wine directly while the asker used wine instead of Playonlinux.
- My ubuntu version is 18.04.01 Bionic Beaver, not 14.04 LTS.
- I am trying to install MS office 2007, not MS office 2010.

I tried several methods.

I successfully mounted the iso-file via the terminal, but Playonlinux is unable to find the CD-ROM, despite the fact that I indicated the path to this mount point (after the successful mounting) in the field "where is your cd-rom mounted".

I chose installation of a non-listed program in POL, browsed the 'setup.exe' file belonging to the folder "ms office" and followed the POL instructions afterwards. There were various messages during the installation process. The was a message that everything is ok, and MS office has been successfully installed on my PC. But those files generated by MS office on another PC are not opened on my PC, and my ubuntu system informs that MS office is not installed. I chose the wine version 3.0.1. in the configuration menu in POL before installation.

Can you give some recommendations and references? What can I do else?

*The above link to another question* did not help me. I followed the recommendation offered for installation of ms office 2007. My ubuntu version requires "Please insert volume 'OFFICE12' (needed for package 'office2007pro')" , despite mounting of OFFICE12.iso

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/155809/can-wine-support-office-2007/258347#258347

Comment: I would install virtualbox, windows in that and office in that. Less hassle. Works 100%. Plus it won't break as easily as wine does.

Comment: @Rinzwind thanks for the advice. But I don't need Microsoft Windows at all. I need to edit some documents prepared by other people with ms office from time to time. I prefer unix-like systems though.