# Can I run MS Office apps installed under windows?

Tags: microsoft-office

I don't have the option of installing the MS Office apps under Wine mostly as I simply don't have them, but these apps do exist on the workstation I use at work.

I have installed Ubuntu on this machine on the same partition as MS Windows via the run-Ubuntu-as-a-Windows-app (not quite verbatim) installation instructions. The MS Windows is XP Professional and the MS Office version is 2007.

Perhaps there are two scenarios, one where I can simply use the apps where they sit, and another where I can somehow "install" the existing executables into Ubuntu (Wine?) rather than installing their iso's (or whatever), which, again, i don't have. Anyway, whatever you can tell me about this is good with me.

Answer (score 4):

MS Office makes extensive use of the Windows registry - for application data and registered DLLs etc.

Lets assume you had two MS Windows installations - you couldnt just point one MS Windows installation at the MS Word executable of the other installation.  It just wouldnt work.

Thus it is the same for Ubuntu.  You will need to have the installation media for MS Office and install it with-in wine or PlayOnLinux.

If you had the actual MS Office documents themselves located on Windows, then you dont need to copy these to Ubuntu - just open Nautilus and browse to your Microsoft partition.

---

Linked Question:

1. [How well does MS Word 2007 and MS Power Point 2007 work in Wine?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/24964/how-well-does-ms-word-2007-and-ms-power-point-2007-work-in-wine)

Comment: @Jorge Castro oops... i've been thinking that since, if i'm remembering correctly, i had given my email in submitting this, that the system would email me when there was a response... o, well... i'm here now and so is the answer... thank you so much for helping me with this... be well, -Rich (interest... i'm reading below "the post author will always be notified of your comment." maybe gmail routed it to the spam folder... i dunno... and now i'm gonna add your username cuz neither do i know if you'll see my thanks w/o doing so.)