# Please help me in installing Ubuntu 12.04.1. and Can it run MS Off. Prof. Plus 2007?

Tags: 12.04, microsoft-office

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How well does MS Word 2007 and MS Power Point 2007 work in Wine?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/24964/how-well-does-ms-word-2007-and-ms-power-point-2007-work-in-wine)

I want to install Ubuntu with MS Office Professional Plus 2007 running. I want to format my hard drive with slow speed as it happens when we install xp. The all cleaning with no traces left.
For that what'll be easy to do: 1) Formatting entire hard drive OR 2) Formatting only that partition on which I want to install Ubuntu?

I should be sure that I can run MS Office Professional Plus 2007 on Ubuntu. I have **ubuntu-12.04.1-desktop-i386.iso** burned on a CD and have MS Office Prof. Plus 2007 in this form -  [http://i.imgur.com/qAhP8.jpg](https://i.imgur.com/qAhP8.jpg)

I also want to know when I update Ubuntu how much MB will it be?

Comment: You are asking at least three different questions. Please (i) separate them and (ii) search askubuntu for answers **first**, because at least two of your questions have been answered many times before.

Comment: Yes I know. My question about partition is already answered. I've seen it at one place. But that was with guy having 2 partitions but I have 3. What I'm confused is that I think Ubuntu don't use C drive, D drive etc. It uses something different for the names of partitions. And also at one place you have to select forward hash "/" and continue. I don't know Ubuntu's structure.

Why I asked this because at one place I've seen that MS office enterprise don't work in new ubuntu well so I was curious. Will Professional Plus work? See this once - http://goo.gl/gQ51h

Answer (score 0):

## Yes you can...

You can install MS Office 2007 in Ubuntu with a addition software called **Wine** or **Play On Linux**. An office package called **Libre Office** comes with Ubuntu 12. I think Libre Office is better than Microsoft Office. It's simple and classic.