# Using WINE to run MS Office

Tags: microsoft-office

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How well does MS Word 2007 and MS Power Point 2007 work in Wine?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/24964/how-well-does-ms-word-2007-and-ms-power-point-2007-work-in-wine)

I have just started to convert from Microsoft windows to Ubuntu. But during the transition I need to run the installed windows MS-office 2007. I have tried, well, what I thought was the instructions but when trying to run power point it would just give me and error "IOPL not enabled", I right clicked the icon and tried to set permissions to run as an executable but it would not stay clicked.

Comment: Please don't post in all caps.  Also your question is too vague to be answered in its current form.  What icon?  Did you create it?  What does it run?  Normally you have to run wine and ask it to run a windows program.

Comment: Why not you try default Libre Office or Open Office. I think they are as good as MS Office.

Answer (score 1):

You will be able to use (If you are using the [latest wine PPA](http://www.winehq.org/download/deb)) Powerpoing 2007 with no problems, but just in case there is PlayOnLinux. In my tests, whichever you choose will work, however, some users have still reported some problems that can be tackled by:

1. Going to `winecfg` and configuring in the library tab the **gdiplus** library to either (native, builtin) or (native, windows).
2. Setting the Wine Prefix variable to your .wine folder. For example if my user is cyrex then:

   `WINEPREFIX="/home/cyrex/.wine"`
3. Using LibreOffice to simply open this files (Assigning this files to be opened with LO). In this case I suggest the latest version since it has some serious updates and fixes regarding Microsoft Office 2003/2007/2010 files.

Since you are showing a [IOPL Bug](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IOPL) I mentioned the 2 first points to fight that problem. But as others might recommend, you should give LibreOffice a try.