# Run winword.exe

Tags: dual-boot, wine

I have dual boot with windows 7 and Ubuntu 14.04. And I want to run the microsoft word (which is installed on windows, not on ubuntu) from Ubuntu using wine, but I get "IOPL not enabled" error. I've already configured wine's library with gdiplus (native,builtin), and still no change, any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Possibly this link could help you`http://askubuntu.com/questions/251467/using-wine-to-run-ms-office`

Comment: I already looked up that link, configured WINEPREFIX from terminal, still no change

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must install it fully under WINE in Ubuntu.  That means grabbing your DVD or install files, and re-installing it from scratch while in Ubuntu.

You cannot run it from your Windows partition.  It requires access to registry values and other data in your local settings to even start, which are in the Windows registry.

WINE has its own registry and "hard drive" with local data.